# Right-aligned Labels in iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, label, text-alignment

I'm using Xamarin Forms.  Some of my labels are right-adjusted (i.e `TextAlignment = TextAlignment.End`) and have a whitespace character in the end to allow a bit of a margin at the right end.  This works as designed in Android.  However, it looks like iOS simply ignores the trailing space.

A leading space, for left-adjusted labels, works fine on both platforms.

I tried different whitespace characters other than `"\u0020"`: `"\u00A0"`, `"\u2000"`, `"\u202F"`, etc.  iOS  ignores them all the same.

I cannot use `Label.Margin` because my label has a different `BackgroundColor`, and the whole idea is to leave a little space of this color at the right of the text.  The `Margin` is considered outside of the label, so the background color won't extend there.

Is placing the label inside a `ContentView` with `Padding` the only solution?

Comment: What layout is holding the label? e.g. StackLayout, RelativeLayout

Comment: `AbsoluteLayout`

Answer (score 0):

## Answer

You're correct: we need to increase the Label's `Padding`, and `Margin` won't accomplish this!

The problem is that `Label` doesn't have a `Padding` property.

I recommend setting the `BackgroundColor` and `Padding` in the Layout that holds the `Label`:

1. Remove the `BackgroundColor` from the Label
2. Assign the `BackgroundColor` to the Layout
3. Set the `Padding` of the Layout

```cs
var stackLayout = new StackLayout 
{
    Children = { rightJustifiedLabel }, 
    BackgroundColor = Color.Red, 
    Padding = new Thickness(0, 0, 5, 0)
}
```

## Sample Code

```cs
public class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        MainPage = new LabelPage();
    }
}

public class LabelPage : ContentPage
{
    public LabelPage()
    {
        var rightJustifiedLabel = new Label
        {
            Text = "Right-Justified Label",
            HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.End,
        };

        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = { rightJustifiedLabel },
            BackgroundColor = Color.Red,
            Padding = new Thickness(0, 0, 5, 0),
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured.  `StackLayout` or `ContentView` or any other `Layout`.  Xamarin Forms suck...  In general, I find myself struggling with minor UI issues that should've been taken care of by now.